# How to get the maximum value of table in MySQL carrying the respective attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have the following `example_table` resulting from a nested query:

```
id    site_ref     area  
-------------------------------
91    Lake SW       0.23
91    Lake MP       3.89
93    Lake SW       0.56
93    Lake MP       0.05
```

I want to get the maximum area per `id` , carrying the respective `site_ref` with it.
I used the following SQL:

```
select id,  site_ref, max(area) from example_table  GROUP BY id
```

What I get is (wrong `site_ref`):

```
id    site_ref     area  
-------------------------------
91    Lake SW       0.56
93    Lake SW       3.89
```

What I want is:

```
id    site_ref     area  
-------------------------------
91    Lake MP       3.89
93    Lake SW       0.56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select et.*
from example_table et
where et.area = (select max(et2.area) from example_table et2 where et2.id = et.id);
```